# Check URL parameter in php

Tags: php, string

I want to check a parameter in a url variable, for example:

```
$var2join = 'en'; // can be anything else
$url = 'https://www.example.com/hello/parameter2';
$url2 = 'https://www.example.com/hello2';
$url3 = 'https://www.example.com/en/hey';
```

first check if the $url vars have the $var2join into $var as parameter if have it, leave it intact and if not add it.

Wanted output:

```
$url = 'https://www.example.com/en/hello/parameter2';
$url2 = 'https://www.example.com/en/hello2';
$url3 = 'https://www.example.com/en/hey';
```

I tried:

```
$url = (!preg_match('~^/[a-z]{2}(?:/|$)~', $location)) ? '/' . $var2join . $url : $url;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [parse_url()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), it is specifically for analysing URLs and their various elements.

Note this code assumes your parameters are path segments, as you describe above.  If you ever use query string parameters like `?foo=bar`, you'd need to adjust.

```
$var2join = 'en';
$url = 'https://www.example.com/hello/parameter2';

// Split URL into each of its parts
$url_parts = parse_url($url);

// Create an array of all the path parts, which correspond to
// parameters in your scheme
$params = explode('/', $url_parts['path']);

// Check if your var is in there    
if (!in_array($var2join, $params)) {

    // If not, reconstruct the same URL, but with your var inserted.
    // NOTE this assumes a pretty simple URL, you'll need to adjust if
    // you ever have other elements like port number, u/p, query strings
    // etc.  @Jason-rush links to something in the PHP docs to handle
    // such cases.
    $url = $url_parts['scheme'] . '://' . $url_parts['host'] . '/' . $var2join . $url_parts['path']; 
}

// Check your result - https://www.example.com/en/hello/parameter2 
echo $url;
```

Comment: If more complex URLs are being used, may want to look at something more thorough to rebuild the URLs like http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php#106731

Comment: No need to explode if you use substr. https://3v4l.org/laG36 - though wont work if var2join is `fr` as it will become `/fr/en/...`

Comment: @LawrenceCherone That code assumes a) `$var2join` is always the first parameter. A reasonable assumption maybe, but not something explicitly stated, so seems risky to me. b) `$var2join` is always 2 chars.  Again, maybe reasonable, but OP did not mention this and I would not assume it.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Yeah, the OP would just need to add all langs in an array and do an additional check which strips out if present before prepending the diff.  Nice answer though.. just though id point it out. :s

Comment: I agree `$var2join` is always the first parameter and always is 2 chars. Works perfect. Thank you for your help @Don'tPanic

Comment: btw, `+2` takes in account the two `/` is not related to the value of var2join

Answer (score 1):

This is a little generic function with some support code to give you some ideas... Not very elegant but it works.

```
<?php

$base_url = 'https://www.example.com/';
$var2join = 'en'; // can be anything else

$url = $base_url . 'hello/parameter2';
$url2 = $base_url . 'hello2';
$url3 = $base_url . 'en/hey';
$url4 = $base_url . 'hey/this/is/longer';



echo prepend_path_to_url($base_url, $url, $var2join);
echo '<br>';
echo prepend_path_to_url($base_url, $url2, $var2join);
echo '<br>';
echo prepend_path_to_url($base_url, $url3, $var2join);
echo '<br>';
echo prepend_path_to_url($base_url, $url4, $var2join);
echo '<br>';

/**
 * Prepend a Path to the url
 *
 * @param $base_url
 * @param $url
 * @param $path_to_join
 * @return string
 */
function prepend_path_to_url($base_url, $url, $path_to_join) {
    // Does the path_to_join exist in the url
    if (strpos($url, $path_to_join) === FALSE) {
        $url_request = str_replace($base_url,'',$url);
        $url = $base_url . $path_to_join . '/'. $url_request;
    }
    return $url;
}
```